# "You can cream on me"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, lyrics

I was listening to "Let it Bleed" by The Rolling Stones, and the lyrics say

> Yeah, we all need someone we can cream on //
> Yeah and if you want to, well you can cream on me

On the Cambridge dictionary, I only find this meaning for cream as a verb

> to make food into a smooth, thick liquid

And for the phrasal verb "cream off" (not *on*):

> to remove the best part of something or the best people in a group and use them for your own advantage

So what does "cream on someone", mean?

Comment: Get a better dictionary, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cream) has a lot of meanings, and there are additional slang meanings (some very sexual) you might find in a slang dictionary or Urban Dictionary. I don't think the song actually means a lot and is just looking for rhymes, but you might be better asking on a music or literature forum.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. There is an explicit tag for lyrics, so why wouldn't questions about lyrics be welcome? Second, there is no definition in Merriam-Webster either for "cream on", and none of the definitions that @StuartF links to have the "on". Urban Dictionary contains a lot of user-submitted meanings so it is hard to find the correct one. Was hoping for a more canonical answer instead of a downvote - the question is clearly in-scope for English.SE.

Comment: Very few questions addressing lyrics pass the 'questions about literary interpretation are off-topic' requirement. Usually, there is no 'canonical' answer. I remember the response of a member of Queen when asked to explain the lyrics of _Bohemian Rhapsody_: "You've got to be joking" owtte. Non-standard usages, open to opinion, no canonical answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough, but I am not convinced that this question has that issue. I can't even find "cream on" as a phrasal verb anywhere. So it's not that I am asking for the in-context, literary interpration of an existing word, but I am asking about the meaning of a construction that I can't find in dictionaries and that, to my non-native ears, does not easily link to meanings of the root "cream".

Comment: I am thankful to the commenters who do try to answer the question. Please feel free to post it as answer that I can accept. It seems that a sexual interpretation is indeed plausible, although that was not what I expected. At least in my own native language, there is no such corresponding construction between "cream" and a sexual act as far as I know.

Comment: @BramVanroy I'm not convinced *cream on* is a phrasal verb; *on* is a simple preposition. It's similar to *He ran on grass* (as the surface, or as food) and *He ran on* (meaning he carried on running, or talking): only the second is a phrasal verb. I'm going to remove the answers from the comments because they shouldn't be there.

Comment: @AndrewLeach any valid reason why my comment about the meaning of "cream" in i sexual context was deleted? Was it too indecent? And yet I did refrain from posting a link to *creampie* and I did say NSFW if the OP were to Google it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - don’t forget the puritanical spirit of this site.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Nothing to do with puritans (I'm Catholic :-) or prurience (I'm catholic :-) but simply that it was more answer than comment.

Comment: Might've suggested that I make it into an answer, but I was pretty certain the question was going to be closed because lyrics interpretation is off-topic and the [secondary (6th) meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cream) is not difficult to find online

Comment: @Mary-LouA - My comment, which showed a reference was also deleted! So I posted it as an answer, which is what it should have been in the first place, prompted by the mod's "I'm going to remove the answers from the comments because they shouldn't be there."

Comment: @WeatherVane I wasn't notified about the risk, and when I checked back my comment was deleted. Too late to do anything now.

Comment: @Mary-LouA the mod's [notification](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610621/you-can-cream-on-me/610627#comment1545919_610621) is still there for all to read.

Comment: Not in my inbox it isn't..

Comment: It looks like an ironic, sexual interpolation of "Lean on Me" by Bill Withers.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Possibly it was the other way round! The song "Lean on me", released in 1972, has the line: "**We all need somebody to lean on**" which is eerily similar to the Stones' lyric “**Well, we all need someone we can lean on**"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Jagger/Richards had to find a number of (full or part) rhyming verbs *(**lean, dream, cream, feed, bleed** on me),* so some of them might be stretching idiomatic usage to the limit.

Note that just a couple of years after the 1969 release of *Let It Bleed* came *Sticky Fingers* (complete with a [zip fly](https://recordart.net/2020/10/03/the-rolling-stones-sticky-fingers-zip-or-no-zip/) built into the album cover). So we might reasonably assume the "primary" reference is to ejaculation (metaphorically, *climax* [for either sex](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22definitely%20creamed%20my%20pants%22)) - particularly because the Rolling Stones did tend to cultivate a more risque "bad boy" image than the Beatles back in the 60s.

So far as I can see, the actual expression [***cream your pants***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cream_in_one%27s_jeans) had little or no currency back then, so censorious prudes wouldn't have had a very strong case for complaining, even if they understood the sexual allusion. Which I think was deliberate, but if someone like [Mary Whitehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Whitehouse) had taken them to court for "gross indecency", they'd probably have had their lawyers argue that no such allusion was intended.

Those lyrics *weren't* tested in court - but if they had been, perhaps the Stones' lawyers would have cited [this 1965 written instance...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hath%20creamed%20his%20pants%22)

> *The smell of the cowdung had by now conquered the perfume-filled atmosphere of the room. "Aaaaaaagh!" said Liz Taylor. "Methinks the gentleman hath **creamed his pants**".*

(i.e. - *defecated*, not *ejaculated*). So they'd say that part of the song is about everyone needing people they can metaphorically shit on (badmouth, look down on) - nothing to do with sex. Not true, imho, but at the time The Rolling Stones, big as they were, would have had to make *some* concessions to censorship.

---

EDIT: It's also worth noting that besides the explicitly *sexual climax* connotations of ***cream*** (far stronger today than at the time) are non-salacious allusions to *[adoringly]* [***creaming = gushing***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gushing%20all%20over%20him%22) (inviting addressee to be "swept off her feet" in affection / admiration / praise for the singer).

Comment: It may be worth noting several other quite sexual lyrics in the song (["there will always be a space in my parking lot", "baby come all over me", etc.](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/The-Rolling-Stones/Let-It-Bleed)), supporting your claim.

Comment: Censorship? Oh yeah. On the Ed Sullivan Show in 1967, the Stones had to change their lyrics from "Let's Spend the Night Together" to "let's spend some time together." https://www.billboard.com/music/music-news/rolling-stones-ed-sullivan-censored-lets-spend-night-together-6436569/  It was reported that Sullivan said, "Either the song goes or you go."

Comment: So "cream on someone" was chosen because it's as sexual as they could be while maintaining legal plausible deniability!

Comment: @Stef: I think *far* more likely ***cream*** was chosen *because it rhymes*. But to the extent that song lyrics like this have any real "meaning", I suppose if any of ***come / climax / ejaculate** on me* had fitted the rhyme pattern, they *wouldn't* have included it anyway, because back in the late 60s in Britain, the record would have been banned for certain.

Comment: (I found no evidence that *anyone* was using *cream on [person]* to mean *ejaculate* on them, at that time. It looks like an obvious metaphor today, but it wasn't really anything at the time - especially in the UK (I think AmE *cream in one's **jeans*** came first anyway).

Comment: FumbleFingers, your last two comments are leaving me confused as to what your answer really is. When I read it, I understood it the same way as @Stef. Now you seem to be saying that these words were not intended to have any meaning at all, that they were just nonsense chosen solely for the sake of rhyming. Is that the answer, then? When you said, in the third sentence, 'we might reasonably assume', did you intend that it be interpreted as: the assumption would be prima facie reasonable, but, upon investigation turns out to be erroneous?

Comment: @jsw29: Like I said, I found no evidence that ***to cream*** had any currency back then in the "ejaculate" sense. Obviously, just about everyone today will be susceptible to that interpretation (you can't "unthink" something like that). But in reality, I doubt Jagger / Richards had it in mind. Bear in mind I'm a post-modernist, so I'm perfectly happy to say the meaning has changed over the decades, and I don't really care what was in the mind of an author when he wrote something. It's how it plays out in my mind now that counts.

Comment: ...I don't say the words weren't intended to have any meaning. Just that the writers probably didn't have a very clear idea of *exactly* what each word "meant". Song lyrics are often more about suggesting a mood than precisely describing things.

Answer (score 10):

It is a sexual reference.

[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=cream) shows several example usages, which I don't really want to copy/paste into this answer (because they mention explicit sexual behaviour).

Answer (score 8):

If you insist, uhm.."cream on someone" means to ejaculate on someone or in other words, to eject semen on someone. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creampie_(sexual_act)).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community This is the best answer.

Comment: A "best answer" would include references to back it up.  That is what Community's automatic comment means.

Comment: @Community They can find better information on a good answer in one of the probably now banned highschool biology textbooks or supplementary information provided in those classes.

Comment: See [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=creaming) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creampie_(sexual_act))

Comment: Perhaps this is too heteronormative of me but I'd expect that this lyric was directed to a female audience so your answer is a tad confusing.

Comment: @BramVanroy Female ejaculation is also a thing... but it's "we all need someone we can cream *on*" i.e. the singer is 'doing it'

Comment: @FShrike Note the second part: "You can cream on me".